# Changing label position

Tags: java

how can I change the position of the label "enter which city " so that it goes in the centre, underneath all the buttons but above the textbox?

[image]

Comment: Have you already learned about [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)?

Comment: I'm familiar with those but not sure where to add them in this case

Comment: Hint: [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)